# sudo -i touchが特定条件下でアボートする

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, rhel

RHEL5.5にて以下コマンドを実行した際、エラーが出力されてしまいます。

**コマンド例**

```
[TESTUSER]$ sudo -i touch /home/TESTUSER/tmp/testfile
```

**エラー例**

```
*** glibc detected *** sudo: corrupted double-linked list: 0x00002b1de9504cc0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
～略～
======= Memory map: ========
～略～
アボートしました
```

例えば、`sudo -i touch /home/TESTUSER/testfile` と、ホームディレクトリ配下にした場合は問題なく実行できるため、`sudo -i` の仕組みにおいて私の使用方法が悪いのだろうと想定していますが、何故このようになるかご教示いただけますでしょうか。

---------追記------------------
・ディレクトリが作成されていたことは事前に確認済みです
・sudoバージョン：Sudo version 1.7.10p7

よろしければ回答（コメント？）への返信方法をご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: `/home/TESTUSER/tmp/` ディレクトリは予め存在していますか？

Comment: @cubickさん
ディレクトリは作成しております。
sudo -s で実行した結果、問題なく実行できたので恐らくその辺りにヒントがありそうです・・

Comment: [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？ - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: ディスク故障やメモリ故障もしくはsudoのバグなど、本質的には-iオプションとは関係ない部分の問題だったりしませんか？ とりあえずsudoの正確なバージョン及びパッケージのバージョンがあると何かわかるかも。

Comment: 参考までに、"corrupted double-linked list" を表示している箇所は [glibc.git/malloc/malloc.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=fe973770a6eb661e0e2d901ba311fed85a5b3340;hb=c48d92b430c480de06762f80c104922239416826#l1458) で、想定される状況としては double free や free に渡すアドレスが不適切などが挙げられます。類似事例に [Double free or corruption in 2.15 when coupled with sudo](https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-pam/issues/31) があって、こちらは後者(free に渡すアドレスを間違えていた)です。

Comment: @hideonbush 既に hinaloe さんもコメントしていますが、質問投稿時とは別アカウントを作成してしまっている状態なのでコメントや編集が出来ない状態です。 / ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを行って下さい。